# Regex InOgham unicode in java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I need to remove the following charachters in the strings that I receive:

```
U+0020 (space)
U+00A0 (no-break space)
U+1680 (ogham space mark)
U+2000 (en quad)
U+2001 (em quad)
U+2002 (en space)
U+2003 (em space) 
U+2004 (three-per-em space) 
U+2005 (four-per-em space) 
U+2006 (six-per-em space) 
U+2007 (figure space) 
U+2008 (punctuation space) 
U+2009 (thin space) 
U+200A (hair space) 
U+202F (narrow no-break space) 
U+205F (medium mathematical space) 
U+3000 (ideographic space) 
U+2028 (line separator) 
U+2029 (paragraph separator)
```

I found out that most of the listed ones, I can remove with the following regex:

```
\p{Zs}|\p{Zl}|\p{Zp}
```

This should cover everything, except the U+1680. According to [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), the pattern for the *ogham space mark* should be `\p{InOgham}`, but when I went to test it on regex tester websites, none of them accepted it.
Is there a specific expression for this, or is it also covered by `\p{Zs}`?

Comment: InOgham is the [whole ogham block](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/ogham/list.htm). Anyway, `\u1680` is probably a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode character U+1680 is an Ogham space mark, which differs from the standard space character (U+0020) and the other space characters you listed.

In Java's regular expressions, the `\p{Z}` character class represents any Unicode separator character, which includes all the space characters you listed except for U+1680. Therefore, the regular expression `\p{Zs}|\p{Zl}|\p{Zp}` should match all the space characters you listed except for U+1680.

To precisely match the Ogham space mark (U+1680), you can use the `\p{InOgham}` character class, which matches any character in the Ogham Unicode block. Here's an example regex pattern that matches all the space characters you listed, including U+1680:

```
[\p{Zs}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{InOgham}]
```

You can use this pattern with a String.replaceAll() method call to remove all occurrences of these space characters from a string:

```
String input = "some string with spaces and \u1680 ogham space marks";
String output = input.replaceAll("[\\p{Zs}\\p{Zl}\\p{Zp}\\p{InOgham}]", "");
System.out.println(output); // prints "somestringwithspacesandoghamspacemarks"
```